# Google Places API is returning inconsistent results (less than 200)

Tags: json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with the Google Places API making an application that will grab place data and display it to users based on their location but I am getting some odd behaviour with the API it is as follows:

I will make a couple different requests such as:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=40.7128,-74.0059&radius=50000&type=restaurant&key=(api-key)
(This is New York City) But even with a 50km radius I get < 200 results which is the advertised max result count. There should be significantly more than 187 (my result count) restaurants within a 50km radius of that point in New York City.

[image]

I also tried this in Vancouver, BC, Canada:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=49.256639,%20-123.097963&radius=50000&type=restuarant&key=(api-key)
And I got 198 results, when I know for a fact there are thousands of restaurants in the Greater Vancouver Area. As can be seen below this is a 50 Km radius circle over Vancouver.

[image]

As my application depends on having that hard max (200) to determine if the radius needs to shrink or grow this behaviour seems out of the ordinary. I do know it used to work this way as an older application of mine was able to use the hard max to shrink/grow dynamically on calls.

Comment: I tested and I get 189 results back from using the first link. I have a project that I use nearby search that I found an area that returns inconsistent results, and it turns out to be a bug and reported.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua Thank you, I made a mistake or at least mine is now returning 186 for the first query, still wrong but I had 187 above.

Comment: If I set the radius to 1km (at least in NYC) I get 200 results. For Vancouver, I get 199 results.

Comment: @geocodezip ok but that still doesn't make any sense as 50km should give me 200 results. And I believe 1 km in Vancouver should as well (much like NYC).